# Changing Airline-Vim z section

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline

Currently my z section looks cramped. Is there any way I could add a bit more separation between the symbols?

[image]

I would like to separate "≡" from the "%"

Comment: I think your system has a problem with the `colnr` symbol. I'd suggest to try to use a different symbol, see e.g. https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/5d7e6560817138110abec3e5c9903b408bc21f51/doc/airline.txt#L397

Comment: You were right, I changed it to something different and it works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ChristianBradandt said, I had an incompatibility problem with my font. The following worked for me:

On my vimrc I wrote:

```
let g:airline_symbols.colnr = '  ㏇:'
```

However, you could replace "㏇" with whichever symbol you like. For more information, https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/5d7e6560817138110abec3e5c9903b408bc21f51/doc/airline.txt#L397